# Will Graphic Card with PCIe 2.0 version using on PCIe x16 1.1 affect graphic cards performance?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

These are my [motherboard specs](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/740GM-P25.html#/?div=Detail).

> **Slots**
>
> 1 PCI Express x16 slot (PCI Express Bus SPEC V1.1a compliant)
>
> 2 PCI Express x1 slots
>
> 1 PCI slot, support 3.3V/ 5V PCI bus Interface.

See the version of PCIe slot.

---

**Processor:** Phenom x2 555 (3.2GHz)

I am planning to purchase [Nvidia GeForce GT 630](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-630/specifications).

Will this card run smoothly on my motherboard as with normal PCIe 2.0 version does? Or do I have compromise with backward compatibility & if so will that compromise be really big or just little which won't be visible? Should I go for it?

Comment: It will work fine but on average it will be somewhat (2% - 10%)  slower then on a PCI-e v2 or v3 connection. Note that variations on this question have been asked several times before.

Answer (score 2):

The card will run smoothly.  The 630 is low end compared to 670 or 680.  The difference for a 630 will probably be so small as not to matter.  It would be a whole different story if you were buying a 670 or 680.

Additional note:  You may still experience low frames rate if you push any game too far.  Run at 1920x1080 or higher with everything set to max and the 630 will slow down or be unplayable. The card plugged into a PCIE 2.0 slot will not fare any better with the settings maxed out.